# Why class files not generating while creating RESTful Web Service?

Tags: jboss, jax-rs

I am trying to create and deploy a simple web service on a JBOSS(Wildfly) Application Server.My code is a s follows:

```
package demo.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("hello")
public class HelloWorld {
    
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getText() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    

}
```

And My web.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RestProject</display-name>
  <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
 
    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
 
    <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>
 
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
 
</web-app>
```

When I am running as server, .class files are not generating under Wildfly->Standalone->Deployements -> WEB-INF -> classes folder.Can you please suggest any solution for this.Since the .class files are not generation,in the browser I am getting Error:404 (http://localhost:8080/RestProject/rest/wines)

Comment: How are you building and deploying your application?

Comment: This is the only code i have.I was just trying write a class file that implements a web service and deploy it.